# Update collection based on another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two mongo collections,

1. User Materials collection

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId("642211ab7819cd5543caa844"),
  id: new ObjectId("642211ab7819cd5543caa843"), //Users ID 
  fish: [
    { id: new ObjectId("64137761acb82c1ae1e4413d"), quantity: 0 },
    { id: new ObjectId("641377e9acb82c1ae1e48a53"), quantity: 10 },
    { id: new ObjectId("6413785aacb82c1ae1e4c5d5"), quantity: 5 },
    { id: new ObjectId("641378b7acb82c1ae1e4f740"), quantity: 5 },
    { id: new ObjectId("64137907acb82c1ae1e5214d"), quantity: 0 },

  ],
  decorations: [
    { id: new ObjectId("64209d8c0b6bc2004048c70a"), quantity: 15 },
    { id: new ObjectId("64209daef663d1d01c92b7bb"), quantity: 0 },
    { id: new ObjectId("64209dc3f663d1d01c92b7be"), quantity: 0 },
    { id: new ObjectId("64209dd3f663d1d01c92b7c1"), quantity: 0 },
  ],
}
```

2. Pre builds collection

```json
  {
    "_id": "642f6a179111d58d2f5e12fc",
    "name": "Beta build",
    "MainFish": "64136fadebe17abf2ff9157f",
    "tank": "642eb506d25567fbf2bfba88",
    "fish": [
      {
        "id": "64136fadebe17abf2ff9157f",
        "quantity": 1,
        "craftable": false
      },
      {
        "id": "641379e6acb82c1ae1e59c33",
        "quantity": 2,
        "craftable": false
      }
    ],
    "decorations": [
      {
        "id": "64209e52f663d1d01c92b7d9",
        "quantity": 2,
        "craftable": false
      }
      {
        "id": "64209dd3f663d1d01c92b7c1",
        "quantity": 1,
        "craftable": false
      }
    ],
    "utilities": [
      {
        "id": "642207ffc56e15f65b9ddaef",
        "quantity": 1,
        "craftable": false
      },
      {
        "id": "64220815c56e15f65b9ddaf5",
        "quantity": 1,
        "craftable": false
      }
    ],
    "remainingSpace": 10,
    "__v": 0
  },
```

I'm trying to find the corresponding ids and check whether the first collection meets the quantity requirement from the second and update the craftable boolean value. What I have now technically works, but I know its not good practice nor should I be doing it as a last resort.

```js
async function getallBuilds(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
        const userId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('642211ab7819cd5543caa843');
        const populateAreas = {
            path: 'id name imagePath Litres',
            select: 'id name imagePath Litres'
        }
        const builds = await preBuilds.find()
        .populate({
            path: 'MainFish',
            select: 'imagePath',
            model: FishModel
        }).populate({
            path: 'fish',
            populate: {
                ...populateAreas,
                model: FishModel,
            },
        }).populate({
            path: 'decorations',
            populate: {
                ...populateAreas,
                model: DecorationModel,

            },
        }).populate({
            path: 'utilities',
            populate: {
                ...populateAreas,
                model: UtilityModel,
            },
        }).populate({
            path: 'tank',
            select: 'Litres',
            model: TankModel
        })
        const user = await userMats.findOne({ id: userId });

        console.log(user)

        if (user !== null) {
            for (const userFish of user.fish) {
                for (const build of builds) {
                    for (const fish of build.fish) {
                        console.log(fish)
                        if (userFish.quantity >= fish.quantity) {
                            await preBuilds.updateOne({ 'fish.id': userFish.id }, { $set: { 'fish.$.craftable': true } });

                        } else {
                            await preBuilds.updateOne({ 'fish.id': userFish.id }, { $set: { 'fish.$.craftable': false } });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ msg: `User with ${userId} does not have inventory` })
        }
        if (!builds) {
            return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'no Builds were found' })
        }
        return res.status(200).json(builds)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(200).json({ error: error })
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!